# SELECT * FROM table while condition=true?

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to select something from table while one condition is true,

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM`table1` `t1` ORDER BY t1.date) `t2` WHILE t2.id!=5
```

when `while condition` comes to false it stop selecting next rows.

Please help me, I have already search a lot and many similars in `stackoverflow` but I can't get it.

please don't tell me about `where` , i want solution in sql not in php or anything other

OK the real problem is here

```
SELECT *,(SELECT SUM(t2.amount) FROM (select * from transaction as t1 order by t1.date) `t2`) as total_per_transition FROM transaction
```

here i want to calculate total balance on each transaction

Comment: its not working i know i want somthing for `while`

Comment: It is not a greatest-n-per-group problem.

Comment: do u have any colunm in table that increase only...like identity

Comment: You have to ask a question on a **real problem** you have, not regarding some tool you choose. What data and on what condition you want to retrieve?

Comment: yes, but that will always increase , i won't be dependent on it its ID

Comment: ok, editing real problem

Comment: ok can you show the  table schema and name the column that increase always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find the first date where the condition fails, so where `id=5`:

```
SELECT date 
FROM table1
WHERE id = 5 
ORDER BY date
  LIMIT 1
```

Then make the above a derived table (we call it `lim`) and join it to the original table to get all rows with previous dates: `t.date < lim.date`

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table1 AS t
  JOIN
  ( SELECT date 
    FROM table1
    WHERE id = 5 
    ORDER BY date
      LIMIT 1
  ) AS lim
    ON t.date < COALESCE(lim.date, '9999-12-31') ;
```

The `COALESCE()` is for the case when there are no rows at all with `id=5` - and in that case we want all rows from the table.